# Bootstrap fixed position left column that becomes fixed when footer in view

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a left column on my website that becomes fixed when scrolling downward then when it fits the footer it becomes absolute positioned at the bottom. When the user scrolls upward it becomes fixed again but the user can still scroll to the top of the column.

The exact behaviour I am trying to emulate can be seen here: https://store.google.com/gb/collection/accessories_wall.

When the user scrolls the page the left col has a fixed position but still scrolls to the bottom. When the user gets to the footer the behaviour changes to become absolute positioned. When the user scrolls upward the column becomes fixed again but still allows the user to scroll to the top of the column.

I've created a JSFiddle of where I am at so far: https://jsfiddle.net/peLwk1cs/2/ and included here for reference but if anyone can help to get it working like the Google example I would be most grateful.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var filterCol = $('.filterContainer');
                var scrollTopPos = $(window).scrollTop();
                
                //Sticky filter col
                if (scrollTopPos > lastScrollTop) {
                    // downscroll code
                    if (scrollTopPos >= 60) {
                        filterCol.addClass("fixed-position");

                        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#resultsCol').offset().top + $('#resultsCol').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
                            filterCol.removeClass("fixed-position");
                            filterCol.addClass("absolute-to-bottom");
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                    // upscroll code
                        filterCol.removeClass("absolute-to-bottom");
                        filterCol.removeClass("fixed-position");
                    }
                }
                lastScrollTop = scrollTopPos;    
            });
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#0000ff;
}

footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#00ff00;
}

#filtersCol {
  position: relative;
}

.filterContainer {
  background-color:#ddd;
  height: 1200px;
}

.fixed-position {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: auto;
        width: 24vw;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        margin-top: 110px;
        height: 1200px;
    }

    .absolute-to-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 24vw;;
    }


#resultsCol {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="filtersCol" class="col col-4">
      <div class="filterContainer">
        FILTER COL FOR FIX/ABSOLUTE
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="resultsCol" class="col col-8">
      RESULTS COL
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to use `sticky-top` and then you don't need the JS...

```
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="filtersCol" class="col col-4">
            <div class="filterContainer sticky-top"> FILTER COL </div>
        </div>
        <div id="resultsCol" class="col col-8"> RESULTS COL </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/XLuCu9WTo1

Also, if you want the header to be fixed, you would add the following to adjust for the height of the header...

```
body {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.sticky-top {
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour I'm trying to replicate can be seen on this JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bN4qu/5/

So when the user scroll downwards, the left col sticks when it reaches the bottom. sticky-top keeps the left col at the top which isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

When the user scrolls upwards, the left col sticks to the top correctly.

The JSFiddle example is in CoffeeScript which isn't used in the project sadly and we're using a newer JQuery too.

```
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="side" id="stick">
    TOP OF LEFT COL
    <div class="bottom">
      BOTTOM OF LEFT COL
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">MAIN CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    background: red;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
.side {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main {
    height: 2500px;
    margin: 0;
    background: lightgray;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 300px;
    background: orange;
}


$.fn.stickyTopBottom = (options = {}) ->
    # only works in browsers that support CSS3 transforms (i.e. IE9+)

    ## ##############
    #initialization
    options = $.extend  
      container: $('body') #reference element for starting and stopping the sticking 
(doesn't actually have to contain the element)
      top_offset: 0 #distance from top of viewport to stick top of element
      bottom_offset: 0 #distance from bottom of viewport to stick bottom of element
    , options

    $el = $(this)

     #Get the top of the reference element. If the container moves, would need to move this into scroll handler. 
    #If the container is translated Y, then this method will fail I believe.
    container_top = options.container.offset().top 
    element_top = $el.offset().top

    viewport_height = $(window).height()
    $(window).on 'resize', -> 
      viewport_height = $(window).height()


     ## #################
    # The meat: scroll handler
    #
    # When moving up or element is shorter than viewport:
    #    if scrolled above top of element, position top of element to top of viewport
    #      (stick to top)
    # When moving down: 
    #    if scrolled past bottom of element, position bottom of element at bottom of viewport
    #      (stick to bottom)

    current_translate = 0
    last_viewport_top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
    $(window).scroll (event) ->
      viewport_top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
      viewport_bottom = viewport_top + viewport_height
  effective_viewport_top = viewport_top + options.top_offset
  effective_viewport_bottom = viewport_bottom - options.bottom_offset

  # Need to reset element's height each scroll event because it may have change height 
  # since initialization.
  # Warning: checking height is performance no-no
  element_height = $el.height()

  is_scrolling_up = viewport_top < last_viewport_top
  element_fits_in_viewport = element_height < viewport_height

  new_translation = null
  if is_scrolling_up
    if effective_viewport_top < container_top # if we're scrolled past container top
      new_translation = 0
    else if effective_viewport_top < element_top + current_translate
      new_translation = effective_viewport_top - element_top

  else if element_fits_in_viewport
    if effective_viewport_top > element_top + current_translate
      new_translation = effective_viewport_top - element_top

  else # scrolling down
    container_bottom = container_top + options.container.height() #warning: checking height is performance no-no
    if effective_viewport_bottom > container_bottom #scrolled past container bottom
      new_translation = container_bottom - (element_top + element_height)
    else if effective_viewport_bottom > element_top + element_height + current_translate
      new_translation = effective_viewport_bottom - (element_top + element_height)

  if new_translation != null
    current_translate = new_translation
    $el.css 'transform', "translate(0, #{current_translate}px)" 

  last_viewport_top = viewport_top

 $('#stick').stickyTopBottom
  container: $('#content')
```